# Validating a Sudoku Board in Python

Tags: python, programming-challenge

The [problem statement](https://www.codewars.com/kata/63d1bac72de941033dbf87ae/train/python) is as follows:

> [Sudoku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku) is a game played on a 9x9 grid. The goal of the game is to fill
> all cells of the grid with digits from 1 to 9, so that each column,
> each row, and each of the nine 3x3 sub-grids (also known as blocks)
> contain all of the digits from 1 to 9.
>
> #### Sudoku Solution Validator
>
> **Write a function that accepts a Sudoku board, and returns true if it is a valid Sudoku solution, or false otherwise. The cells of the input
> Sudoku board may also contain 0's, which will represent empty cells.
> Boards containing one or more zeroes are considered to be invalid
> solutions.

Here is my code which passes all the test cases.

I would like feedback on performance, clarity, and readability.
Thank you

```
def has_valid_rows(rows):
    VALID_ROW = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

    for row in rows:
        if 0 in row or set(row) != set(VALID_ROW):
            return False

    return True



def has_valid_columns(columns):
    VALID_COLUMN = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

    for column in columns:
        if 0 in column or set(column) != set(VALID_COLUMN):
            return False
    
    return True



def has_valid_subgrids(input_board):
    VALID_SUBGRID = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

    top_left_subgrid = input_board[0][:3] + input_board[1][:3] + input_board[2][:3]
    top_middle_subgrid = input_board[0][3:6] + input_board[1][3:6] + input_board[2][3:6]
    top_right_subgrid = input_board[0][6::] + input_board[1][6::] + input_board[2][6::]

    middle_left_subgrid = input_board[3][:3] + input_board[4][:3] + input_board[5][:3]
    middle_middle_subgrid = input_board[3][3:6] + input_board[4][3:6] + input_board[5][3:6]
    middle_right_subgrid = input_board[3][6::] + input_board[4][6::] + input_board[5][6::]

    bottom_left_subgrid = input_board[6][:3] + input_board[7][:3] + input_board[8][:3]
    bottom_middle_subgrid = input_board[6][3:6] + input_board[7][3:6] + input_board[8][3:6]
    bottom_right_subgrid = input_board[6][6::] + input_board[7][6::] + input_board[8][6::]

    subgrids = [top_left_subgrid, top_middle_subgrid, top_right_subgrid, middle_left_subgrid, middle_middle_subgrid, middle_right_subgrid, bottom_left_subgrid, bottom_middle_subgrid, bottom_right_subgrid]

    for subgrid in subgrids:
        if set(subgrid) != set(VALID_SUBGRID) or 0 in subgrid:
            return False

    return True



def validate_sudoku(board):
    rows = board
    columns = zip(*board)
    
    if has_valid_rows(rows) and has_valid_columns(columns) and has_valid_subgrids(board):
        return True

    return False
```

Comment: This is [CodeWars' version](https://www.codewars.com/kata/63d1bac72de941033dbf87ae/train/python); it's different to [LeetCode 36](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-sudoku/) in the following ways: Cells are represented as int, not string. Cells may also contain 0's, which will represent empty cells. [But] boards containing one or more zeroes are considered to be invalid solutions. Hence you're complicating your code with the early-termination checks `if 0 in row/col/subgrid...` Whereas in LeetCode, cells are represented as strings and allowed to be empty (".")

Comment: Oh and something really basic but important for code legibility: the variable name `input_board` gets used a whole lot, so rename it `board` or `brd` (or even `b`, although that's discouraged). Look how unwieledy the code in your `has_valid_subgrids()` is.

Comment: When you say "performance", this one is a tradeoff between CPU and memory, so which do you prefer? Currently your approach is to make duplicate copies of the data in each row/col/subgrid; more memory-efficient would be to use Python SliceObjects, and iterators. But you don't really need to duplicate the data, only keep value-counts. A lower-memory alternative with decent CPU performance is to make only one pass over each cell of the input grid, keep 9x9x3 counters for counts of each of the 9 values in each of the 9x3 rows/columns/subgrids, and increment all the counters as you go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Naming

Your function names `has_valid_rows` `has_valid_columns` and `has_valid_subgrids` are misleading: they imply that a board with *any* valid row/column/subgrid would return `True`.

`validate_<region>` would be a better fit.

## Simplification

You can remove the `0 in <region>` conditions in your validation methods, as the sets wouldn't be equal if this were `True`.

## Redundancy 1

You define 3 function-level constants (`VALID_ROW`, `VALID_COLUMN` and `VALID_SUBGRID`) to have the same value. Define a single module-level constant instead. And since you ultimately don't need a list but a set, define that constant to be a set: `VALID_SET = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`.

## Redundancy 2

`has_valid_rows` and `has_valid_columns` are logically identical, only variable names differ. `has_valid_subgrids` also has similar logic. They could be combined into a single function which could get passed different arguments.

## Consistency

You split the board in rows and columns inside of the main function before passing them to the validating methods, but split the board in subgrids inside the `has_valid_subgrids` method. It would be better to have consistent calling conventions.

## Use built-ins

The `all` built-in methods allows to check if a condition if `True` for all elements in an iterable, simplifying your various validation methods a bit, and possibly improving performance:

```
all(set(row) == VALID_SET for row in board)
```

## Return a boolean directly

In your `validate_sudoku` function, the pattern:

```
if <condition>:
    return True
return False
```

can be simplified to:

```
return <condition>
```

## Extracting subgrids

Hard-coding each subgrid individually is probably not the best way of getting them. Try to use a list comprehension or a loop instead.

Comment: Strictly we don't even need to define the constant VALID_ROW/COL/SUBGRID = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] and compare each row/col/sg to it, at all. We **only need to verify that a) the set of values in each row/col/sg has length 9, b) that there are no 0's in the board, and that the board only contains integers 1...9**; can do b) in a first pass over board, then do a) and just check that `len(set(values in each row/col/sg)) == 9`